# I am not able to give active class to pageNumber,I am using Bootstrap and AngularJS,uib-pagination

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, bootstrap-4, ui.bootstrap

i have tried pagination using uib-pagination,everything seems to work fine, but the only thing is that i am not able to attach the page number with active class.

```
<uib-pagination 
    class="center-child" 
    total-items="filterData.length" 
    ng-model="page"
    ng-change="pageChanged()" 
    previous-text="&lsaquo;&lsaquo;" 
    next-text="&rsaquo;&rsaquo;" 
    items-per-page=3>
</uib-pagination>
```

Comment: This is pageChanged.

$scope.pageChanged = function() {
    var startPos = ($scope.page - 1) * 3;
  };

Comment: Reformatted the snippet so it's easier to read.